# Not able to collect Crash Dump on FreeBSD 11.0

Tags: freebsd, crash-dumps

I have to debug a crash. But everytime my system crash it failed to dump the crashdump into the swap memory. The erorr i am seeing is:-

**Uptime: 7m32s
Dumping 3735 out of 131037 MB:..1%(ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): WRITE_DMA48. ACB: 35 00 16 c9 c3 40 39 00 00 00 08 00
(ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): CAM status: CCB request was invalid
(ada0:ahcich0:0:0:0): Error 22, Unretryable error
Aborting dump due to I/O error.

** DUMP FAILED (ERROR 22) **
**

In my rc.conf i have set the dumpdev to AUTO and my swap memory is 4GB.
Here is the ouput of fstab:-

```
# Device        Mountpoint      FStype  Options Dump    Pass#
/dev/ada0p2     /               ufs     rw      1       1
/dev/ada0p3     none            swap    sw      0       0
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your swap partition is smaller than your memory.
How do you expect 12 Gig to fit into 4Gig?

Comment: I have changed the swap size to 160Gig. But still the same error.
And by the way its 127Gig  not 12. That's why i have changed it to 160Gig.